# Нужно разделить два значения, хранящиеся в массиве

Tags: ассемблер

Вычислил смещение первого массива и записал полученный элемент в eax

```
mov eax, esi ; // Для A[N+1-k]
mov ecx, N
inc ecx
sub ecx, k
lea eax, [eax + ecx * 4]
mov eax, [eax]
```

Вычислил смещение второго массива и записал полученный элемент в ebx

```
mov ebx, edi ; // Для B[2*N+2-2*k]
mov edx, N
imul edx, 2
add edx, 2
mov ecx, k
imul ecx, 2
sub edx, ecx
lea ebx, [ebx + edx * 4]
mov ebx, [ebx]
```

Теперь не понимаю, как eax разделить на ebx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;-------------------------деление --- 66/3
mov eax, 66
mov edx, 0
mov ebx, 3
div ebx
; делимое  частное остаток
; EDX:EAX    EAX     EDX
```

Comment: Да не, это понятно. А конкретно в моём случае? Я еще пробовал
`cbq
mov eax, eax
mov ebx, ebx
div ebx`

Comment: Делимое находится в EDX:EAX если у тебя числа в EAX и EBX не забудь обнулить EDX перед делением ! mov EDX, 0

Comment: Спасибо! Особенно, за совет про обнуление edx перед делением